# Merge variable amount of rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a huge worksheet with column `A` containing a person's name and column `B` containing job titles for the person in question, like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
| Column A       | Column B                |
|-------------------------------------------
| John Doe       | CEO                     |
|                | CIO                     |
|                | CTO                     |
| Frank Black    | General Manager         |
|                | HR Manager              |
| Tabitha White  | Payroll specialist      |
| Jane Doe       | General Supervisor      |
|                | Superintendent          |
|                | Building maintenance    |
|                | System administrator    |
|                | IT specialist           |
--------------------------------------------
```

My goal is to merge the job titles to a single row in its own column `C`, separated with a comma. However, each person can have anywhere between one to ten titles and I have thousands of personnel in the worksheet.

Working with each person separately is out of the question, so I'm looking for the most efficient (or easiest) way to achieve this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Column A       | Column B              | Column C                                                                                      |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| John Doe       | CEO                   | CEO, CIO, CTO                                                                                 |
|                | CIO                   |                                                                                               |
|                | CTO                   |                                                                                               |
| Frank Black    | General Manager       | General Manager, HR Manager                                                                   |
|                | HR Manager            |                                                                                               |
| Tabitha White  | Payroll specialist    | Payroll specialist                                                                            |
| Jane Doe       | General Supervisor    | General Supervisor, Superintendent, Building Maintenance, System administrator, IT specialist |
|                | Superintendent        |                                                                                               |
|                | Building maintenance  |                                                                                               |
|                | System administrator  |                                                                                               |
|                | IT specialist         |                                                                                               |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So far I've had no luck trying to duplicate formulas very efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do that with formula but if that's okay to use VBA try something like this:

```
Sub newMacro()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim posName As Integer
    Dim val As String

    val = Cells(1, 2).Value
    posName = 1

    For i = 2 To 1200
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
            val = val + "," + Cells(i, 2).Value
        Else
            Cells(posName, 3).Value = val

            val = Cells(i, 2).Value
            posName = i
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The macro isn't optimized but that should work.. In the For just change the 1200 Value to the number of line your want to process.

Comment: I have zero understanding in Excel macros but this did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A rather clunky solution:

Use a work column, e.g. Column `D`.

In cell `D1` have the following formula:

```
=IF(A1="",
IF(A2="",IF(D2="",B1,CONCATENATE(B1,", ",D2)),B1),
IF(A2="",IF(D2="",B1,CONCATENATE(B1,", ",D2)),B1)
)
```

Have the following formula in cell `C1`:

```
=IF(A1="","",D1)
```

Copy the formula down the columns so that respective references all work.

I suspect there are things to do with pivot tables that do things in a clearer way - not something I've played with though.